# How to make variable in the class into a global variable for later use?

Tags: python

I need to make the local variable in a class into a global variable. It gives an error if I try to make a local variable in a class global. As you can see in the code I would like to get the `temp_username` and `temp_username1` to be a global variable for later use but the class would not let me.

```
class TwoPlayers:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.top_frame = tk.Frame(self.master, relief="solid")
        self.top_frame.pack(side="top", fill="none", expand=True)
        self.label_1 = tk.Label(self.top_frame, text="Player1 Name: ")
        self.label_1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w", padx=5, pady=5)
        self.label_1 = tk.Label(self.top_frame, text="Player2 Name: ")
        self.label_1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w", padx=5, pady=5)
        self.username_entry = tk.Entry(self.top_frame, width=20)
        self.username_entry .grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.username_entry1 = tk.Entry(self.top_frame, width=20)
        self.username_entry1 .grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.save_button = tk.Button(self.top_frame, text="Save", command=lambda: self.read_username())
        self.save_button.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=20)
        self.name_valid = False
        self.username = None

    def read_username(self):
        temp_username = self.username_entry.get()
        temp_username1 = self.username_entry1.get()
        if temp_username == '':
            print("No valid name")
            return
        else:
            self.name_valid = True
            self.username = temp_username
            self.username1 = temp_username1
            print(temp_username) #Shows the input name of the player can be deleted later
            print(temp_username1)
            self.master.destroy()
```

Comment: Global variables should be defined outside of any class (by setting them to a value) and can be declared `global` in a function. But normally you should avoid using global variables.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using just temp_username, make use of static variable, that is TwoPlayers.temp_username and TwoPlayers.temp_username1 inside the print function.

You can also use self.temp_username and self.temp_username1, which indicates an instance variable.